One project in Logic Pro just won't allow me to click into numeric inputs for any Region
I have Logic Pro X 10.8.1 Rosetta, and I have one specific project that I've been working on for a while that has all of a sudden started doing something odd. For all regions in the project, if I open the region settings, I cannot click into the numeric input fields, nor can I usually open "More" dropdown (though it has worked a few times as shown below).
This was working fine until just a little bit ago. Other projects work fine. I have tried restarting my computer. I've tried unplugging all peripherals. I've tried saving the project to a new file and that doesn't help. I have looked through all project settings. Help!
Here is a little demo
https://youtu.be/L-B54fVsLDM

